# Writes in io_uring do not advance the file offset

Tags: linux, io, io-uring

I'm writing some data to disk with `io_uring` and noticed that the file offset does not increase automatically after a write request is issued. Thus, if I issue two write requests through `liburing`, the second one will overwrite the first one since both are trying to write to the beginning of the file. Using these posix apis by themselves (`write` and `writev`) do not cause any issues, but using them through `liburing` never advances the file offset. The man page for `liburing` says setting `offset` to -1 will advance the file offset automatically, but that does not seem to be the case.

A small example is below. The expected behavior is that 4096 bytes of numbers from 0 to 1023 are written to the file, followed by 4096 bytes of 0s. However, the file only contains 4096 bytes of 0s. If I remove the line `write_buffer_to_file(2)`, it now contains 4096 bytes of numbers, so it seems that the second call is overwriting the content of the first one. The fact that `lseek` always returns 0 confirms that the file offset never changes.

The code snippet is compiled with gcc and ran on RHEL 9.3 with kernel 5.14.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <liburing.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// a small macro to check for errors
#define SYSCALL(expr) if ((expr) < 0) { \
    perror("System call error");        \
}

const int WRITE_SIZE = 4096; // satisfy alignment requirement of O_DIRECT
int fd; // file descriptor
int *buffer; // write buffer
struct io_uring ring;

// write the content of the buffer to fd; the data argument sets user_data in the sqe, which shouldn't affect the result
void write_buffer_to_file(int data) {
    struct io_uring_sqe *sqe = io_uring_get_sqe(&ring);
    io_uring_sqe_set_data(sqe, (void*)(intptr_t)data);
    // according to the documentation, setting offset to -1 will advance the offset
    // neither 0 nor -1 work in my testing
    io_uring_prep_write(sqe, fd, buffer, WRITE_SIZE, -1);
    SYSCALL(io_uring_submit(&ring))
    std::cout << "Submitted " << sqe->user_data << std::endl;

    // now wait for it to complete
    struct io_uring_cqe *cqe;
    SYSCALL(io_uring_wait_cqe(&ring, &cqe));
    if (cqe->res < 0) {
        perror("cqe res less than 0");
        std::cerr << std::strerror(-cqe->res) << std::endl;
    }
    io_uring_cqe_seen(&ring, cqe);
    std::cout << "Reaped " << io_uring_cqe_get_data(cqe) << std::endl;
    // this line always prints 0 even though it's supposed to advanced 4096 bytes
    std::cout << "Current offset: " << lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // set up the file and the write buffer
    fd = open("test_file", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_DIRECT, 0744);
    SYSCALL(fd);
    // O_DIRECT has stricter memory alignment requirements
    posix_memalign((void**)&buffer, 512, WRITE_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < WRITE_SIZE / sizeof(int); i++) {
        buffer[i] = i;
    }
    
    io_uring_queue_init(5, &ring, 0);
    write_buffer_to_file(1);

    // set everything in the buffer to 0 and then write again
    memset(buffer, 0, WRITE_SIZE);
    write_buffer_to_file(2);

    io_uring_queue_exit(&ring);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```